# Automatic ID3 tag finder

Tags: macos, itunes, mp3, id3

Does one exist? I have about 500 songs with out ID3 tags and i'm not about to go through and edit 500 songs manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload). It works by generating a fingerprint for each audio file and comparing that with the MusicBrainz database for close matches. At the very least it should cut your workload down quite a bit, so it's a good place to start.

Comment: Picard is probably the best of the lot.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried MP3tag ([Here](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/))? It's what i've been using for quite some time, and I have yet to have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

[ID3 Editor](http://download.cnet.com/ID3-Editor/3000-2170_4-10577448.html) is said to "rename the track file based on the track and title." Would that help?